# Not able to see Pod when I create a Job

Tags: kubernetes, rancher

When I try to create Deployment as Type Job, it's not pulling any image.

Below is .yaml:

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: copyartifacts
spec:
  backoffLimit: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      name: copyartifacts
    spec:
      restartPolicy: "Never"
      volumes:
      - name: sharedvolume
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: shared-pvc
      - name: dockersocket
        hostPath:
          path: /var/run/docker.sock
      containers:
      - name: copyartifacts
        image: alpine:3.7
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        command: ["sh", "-c", "ls -l /shared; rm -rf /shared/*; ls -l /shared; while [ ! -d /shared/artifacts ]; do echo Waiting for artifacts to be copied; sleep 2; done; sleep 10; ls -l /shared/artifacts; "]
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /shared
          name: sharedvolume
```

Can you please guide here?

Regards,
Vikas

Comment: Why do you think it's not pulling any image?

Comment: Could you please format the yaml in your question. See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Comment: Did you do a `kubectl describe deployment <your deployment-name>`? What does it say? It could be that your container registry is not reachable or your cluster does not have the permissions to access it.

Comment: @PeterIttner it's a `Job` not `Deployment`. So, he should use `kubectl describe job <your job-name>`

Comment: are you using minikube or? Are you getting an error?

Comment: Found the root cause for the issue. It issue in yaml file. Belo part I removed from yaml : - name: dockersocket
        hostPath:
          path: /var/run/docker.sock

Comment: Could you be polite and start marking your questions as answered please?

Answer (score 6):

There could be two possible reasons for not seeing pod.

1. The pod hasn't been created yet.
2. The pod has completed it's task and terminated before you have noticed.

**1. Pod hasn't been created:**

If pod hasn't been created yet, you have to find out why the job failed to create pod. You can view job's events to see if there are any failure event. Use following command to describe a job.

```
kubectl describe job <job-name> -n <namespace>
```

Then, check the `Events:` field. There might be some events showing pod creation failure with respective reason.

**2. Pod has completed and terminated:**

Job's are used to  perform one-time task rather than serving an application that require to maintain a desired state. When the task is complete, pod goes to completed state then terminate (but not deleted). If your Job is intended for a task that does not take much time, the pod may terminate after completing the task before you have noticed.

As the pod is terminated, `kubectl get pods` will not show that pod. However, you will able to see the pod using `kubectl get pods -a` command as it hasn't been deleted.

You can also describe the job and check for completion or success event.

Comment: `kubectl get pods -a` is deprecated, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/57309483/5781647

Answer (score 0):

if you use kind created the K8s cluster, all the cluster node run as docker. If you had reboot you computer or VM, the cluster (pod) ip address may change,  leeding to the cluster node internet communication failed. In this case, see the cluster manager logs, it has error message. Job created, but pod not.

try to re-create the  cluster, or change the node config about ip address.