# Anyway to reload the deleted pods from kubernetics cluster

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, rancher

I want to reload the deleted pods from the Kubernetes cluster . Is that possible?.

Is there a way to get some details about the Kubernetes pod that was deleted (stopped, replaced by new version).

Answer (score 1):

There is the option -p if with you want to check the logs from terminated pods.

*-p, --previous=false: If true, print the logs for the previous instance of the container in a pod
if it exists.*

```
kubectl logs -p terminated-pod-name
```

The pod itself is ephemeral as well as its information unless you keep them with a persistent volume you are not able to recover such information once the pod is terminated/deleted. If you need to debug the pod you can use the describe.

```
kubectl describe pod pod-name
```

Comment: do we have options for list all the pods which were deleted?

Comment: There is no a native command to check this, but you can run this command to check the events related with the name of objects that suffered some alteration, that includes the recent deleted/terminated pods: `kubectl get event -o custom-columns=NAME:.metadata.name | cut -d "." -f1`.

Comment: Also you can run this command: `kubectl get event --sort-by .metadata.name | cut -d "." -f1` is very similar but provides more information.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a deployment object, you may fetch the last deployed versions or may rollback to previous versions based on the revision history value set in the deployment object.

As explained by @Bartosz Bilicki here [How to list Kubernetes recently deleted pods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40636021/how-to-list-kubernetes-recently-deleted-pods) you can also fetch the data from the events.

I hope it helps.