# How to find the previous pod names after redeployment in kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes

I redeployed my application with `helm upgrade`, e.g.

```
helm upgrade myapp helm/myapp  --install --namespace=myapp --set image=myapp:latest
```

Then with

```
kubectl get pods
```

I can see new pods get started and old pods get terminated. I wonder once the old pods are terminated, and gone from `kubectl get pods`, can I still find their pod names somehow?

Comment: What kind of changes did you make while upgrading? Paste exact command you have used ?

Comment: @Malgorzata, I updated the description of my question with more details.

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays  `$ kubectl get pods -a`  is deprecated, and as a result you cannot get deleted pods.

However you can get a list of recently deleted pod names - up to 1 hour in the past unless you changed the  `ttl`  for kubernetes events - by executing command:

`$ kubectl get event -o custom-columns=NAME:.metadata.name | cut -d "." -f1`

Take a look: [deleted-pods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40636021/how-to-list-kubernetes-recently-deleted-pods).

For future consider [auditing](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/audit/). Kubernetes auditing gives a security chronological set of records documenting the sequence of activities that have affected system by administrators, users or other components of the system.