# How to revive a deleted pod?

Tags: kubernetes

I force deleted a pod using the command  "kubectl delete pod --grace-period=0 --force --namespace " I expected the pod to regenerate itself but it has not and now I cannot even locate the pod anymore. Is there a way to regenerate a kubernetes pod that has once been deleted or do I need to replace it with a new pod? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hey, so they removed that feature...

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40636021/how-to-list-kubernetes-recently-deleted-pods

Answer (score 2):

1. If the pod is not under any deployment or replica set any such resources, it is almost impossible to retrieve the pod back.
2. If you have deployed it manually, you must have had a spec.yaml file where you would have defined the resource spec or if you have deployed via command line, you must have the history in terminal.
3. If you have deployed via pipeline or automation, you know where to search :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the `-a` flag has been removed from [`kubectl pods get`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#get)

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57309483/1890717) has some interesting options

You can probably find it by name but cannot just "bring it back". It would need to be replaced.